# Is it possible to remove carriage returns from messages written to logs using the log4net framework

Tags: log4net

I want to remove carriage returns from strings before they are written to log4net.

Example:

```
    string query = string.Format(@"select
*
from
<a table>
```

There are three \n there so if I log it via:

```
log.Debug(query);
```

I get somewhat of a messy log

The ideal output would have \n stripped.  I can do this:

```
log.Debug(query.Replace("\n",""));
```

But have to remember to do for each call to the **log** method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this with the conversion pattern printf like syntax in the web.config. However, if you want to do this for all levels all the time, you could download the source and alter the internals.

Otherwise, you could create an extension method like so:

```
public static void Debug(this ILog logger, string message, bool removeNewLines)
{
    if (logger == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");

    logger.Debug(removeNewLines ? message.Replace("\n", string.Empty) : message);
}
```

..and then call it like this:

```
log.Debug(query, true);
```

Only problem is you sill have to remember to call this:

```
log.Debug(query, true);
```

Instead of this:

```
log.Debug(query);
```